Help identify this Red dawn like movie, except in Australia
I watched a movie on Netflix a few years back (probably made after 2010), it's title should have basically been "Red Dawn 3: Invading the outback".
A group of Australian kids go on a camping trip in the outback, only to return to find that their hometown has been invaded by the AAA (Ambiguously Asian Army). 
It culminates in the kids managing to blow up a supply bridge with a gas tanker and starting a small resistance. 
It had "Tomorrow" in the name, but whenever I try and google it I just get "The Day After Tomorrow".

Tomorrow, When the War Began - 2010

Based off the novel of the same name.
A group of Australian kids go on a camping trip in the outback, only to return to find that their hometown has been invaded by the AAA (Ambiguously Asian Army).

Country high school student Ellie sets off on a camping trip to "hell's Gate", with close childhood friend Corrie, together with Corrie's boyfriend Kevin, Ellie's next-door neighbour Homer, high school crush Lee and friends Robyn and Fiona.

It culminates in the kids managing to blow up a supply bridge with a gas tanker and starting a small resistance.

The group sneaks back to Wirrawee, and devise a plan to blow up Heron Bridge. Ellie and Fi steal a petrol tanker from the council depot. They park it near the bridge and, while waiting for the rest of the team to take their positions. After being discovered by guards, they rush to drive the tanker forward under the bridge. The plan necessarily brought forward, Homer and Lee scare a herd of cattle onto the bridge, forcing the sentry guards to flee their posts, allowing Ellie to park the tanker under the bridge unhindered. Working together, they manage to explode the tanker, which utterly destroys the bridge. Corrie however is shot as the group escapes.

It had "Tomorrow" in the name, but whenever I try and google it I just get "The day after tomorrow". 
The film is called Tomorrow, When the war Began
